# Accessing Azure IIS logs from within the same website

Tags: azure, iis, logging, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure website configured to write IIS logs to file system. I would like to have a dashboard page within my website where administrators can view reports about traffic on the site, which has been generated by parsing these logs.

I have tried to access the log directory in code by both `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, and by attempting to connect over FTP using FtpLib.

From outside of Azure, I can connect to the FTP and download the logs, but from code running in the Azure website, I cannot.My assumption is that Azure does not allow outbound FTP traffic from website code.

The folder structure for Azure (by inspecting the FTP) looks something like:

Site: `/site/wwwroot`

Logs: `/LogFiles/http/RawLogs`

Within the Azure portal you can create virtual directories, but they are only allowed within /site.

Site is running as an Azure Web Site, MVC 4, Integrated pipeline, 64bit, .NET 4.5, and for FTP I am using FtpLib v1.0.1.2. FtpLib fails at `Login()` with message: Unknown error (0x2ee2)

I am aware that I can change the logging within Azure to log to Blob Storage, however this would result in additional monthly cost. Are there any other options to access these files?

Thanks.

Edit: Have been asked to supply code, here is the FTP version (works locally, not on Azure):

```
using (var ftp = new FtpConnection("XXXXXXXX.windows.net", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX"))
{
    ftp.Open();
    ftp.Login(); //Fails here
    ftp.SetLocalDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/")); //Temp
    ftp.SetCurrentDirectory("/LogFiles/http/RawLogs");                

    foreach (var f in ftp.GetFiles("*.log"))
    {
        ftp.GetFile(f.Name, f.Name, false);
        ftp.RemoveFile(f.Name);
    }              
}
```

And here is the file system version:

```
//var logRoot = Server.MapPath("~/../../LogFiles/http/RawLogs"); //Throws error about traversal outside of site root
//var logRoot = "/LogFiles/http/RawLogs"; //Throws error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\LogFiles\http\RawLogs'. 
var logRoot = "LogFiles/http/RawLogs"; //Throws error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\http\RawLogs'. 
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(logRoot).GetFiles("*.log"))
{
    f.CopyTo(root + f.Name, true);
    f.Delete();
}
```

Comment: I was able to simply use a File.ReadAllLines(...) on a specific file in LogFiles folder and was able to read it. So please check your code. In fact I was able to do a Directory.GetFiles() and get the files. So please check your code. Or post your code for further assessment.

Comment: Are you sure your paths are right? LogFiles are usually stored in C: along with root folder. But I see D: dirve in your paths. I am pretty much sure that you do not have write access behind the root folder you have which includes LogFiles and Site. Path should be like C:\DWASFiles\Sites\customname\VirtualDirectory0\Site and C:\DWASFiles\Sites\customname\VirtualDirectory0\LogFiles

Comment: Yes, those are the paths that Azure shows in the exception. The site is hosted as a Web Site, not a Virtual Machine or anything like that. I am not specifying "D:", that is Azure choosing that. As mentioned in the question, viewing over FTP implies that site code sits in /site/, and logs sit in /LogFiles/. Of course this could be an abstraction of what the files actually look like, as it's FTP, not direct filesystem access.

Comment: When you do a Server.MapPath("~") did you get D Drive? I am pretty much sure it should be C drive. Just do Server.MapPAth("~") and check the path, then what you can do is place a simple text file in LogFiles folder. Using Server.MapPath("~") result do some string manipulations to go to couple of levels top and then concatenate with the text file you manually placed. At each and every step print the message to page using viewbag. Then I am sure you should achieve target. I have a working sample of code with me.

Comment: Thanks, I think that has solved my problem by using Server.MapPath("~/") + @"..\..\LogFiles\http\RawLogs" - it looks like Directory.GetCurrentDirectory and other methods using DirectoryInfo return a path on d:, but Server.MapPath corectly gets the c:\ path. If you wish you can post your comment(s) as an answer rather than a comment and then I will accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: I am glad, my comments were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem with paths to the log files. AzureWebsites uses C Drive, but in your implementation you are getting D Drive. Use `Server.MapPath("~")` and then do string manipulations on top of it to get the right ROOT Path. So Root directory will be having two more directories - `LogFiles` and `Site`. As you already got the Root directory, append it with `LogFiles` directory and read all files from there.

Comment: Thank you. The problems I had accessing it locally were due to my mapping to the filesystem in the wrong way. The correct path at the time of writing is: Server.MapPath("~/") + @"..\..\LogFiles\http\RawLogs" . Access by FTP appears to be blocked, so I abandoned that avenue.